# Speaker ON only for two contacts Android

Tags: java, android

I have a very strange situation.

I'm comparing two string in my if statement. It's very bizarre because in CALL_STATE_RINGING it returns TRUE but, in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK It returns FALSE!!

Here is a part of my code:

```
private String strRegisterNumber1 = "";
private String strRegisterNumber2 = "";
...........
strRegisterNumber1 = fileManager.getItems(0);
strRegisterNumber2 = fileManager.getItems(1);
...........
    switch (state)
    {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.i("DEBUG", "idle");
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

        if (incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber1) || incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber2))
            // returns FALSE here!
        {                   
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) contextMember.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
        }

        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        if (incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber1) || incomingNumber.equals( strRegisterNumber2))
                    // returns TRUE here!!!
        {
          //do something...

        }

        break;
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Edited:

The incomingNumber I'm getting from here:

```
 ServiceReciever.java

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
  }
 }
```

And the strRegisterNumber I'm retrieving from my FileManager, and they are correct.

Comment: Please edit your post with the exact value of both numbers in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incoming number is only returned in CALL_STATE_RINGING as stated in the official document at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

> Broadcast intent action indicating that the call state (cellular) on the device has changed.
>
> The EXTRA_STATE extra indicates the new call state. If the new state
>   is RINGING, a second extra EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER provides the incoming
>   phone number as a String.

Comment: So can I retrieve the incoming number in CALL_STATE_RINGING and use in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK?

Comment: Yes but you have to store the incoming number in a class variable. in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK check if the number is null or not, and if not null then the state before is CALL_STATE_RINGING and you can use the number. In call state CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK you set the variable that hold the number to null again.